# How do I get youtube videos to play on Apple guest account? (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, wifi, safari, video, youtube

I'm running OS X 10.10.1 on a 15" 2012 MacBook Pro.  Recently I installed the Yosemite update and ever since, my WiFi has stopped working.  Specifically, when I press "Turn On" to activate my WiFi, nothing happens. I tried making the WiFi inactive, then turning it back on after rebooting my computer.  This restores the ability to turn on the WiFi and connect to a server for ~5-10minutes, but after that I'm at square one.

I got tired of having to do this, so I switched to my guest account to see if I would have better luck.  So far, I've been able to connect to my network just fine which is both great and confusing at the same time.  The only caveat is that I can't seem to get Youtube videos to stream.  When I go to a video, it just loads and loads but nothing happens.

So my question is: how can I get Youtube videos to stream on a guest account given my situation?  There is no way to go into settings or files, Safari is the only application that appears to be running.   I don't know why this is the case either.  If anyone can also advise on how to reduce these limitations as well, that'd be great.

Oddly enough, right before sending this message my WiFi on guest experienced some difficulties. Now I'm using an ethernet cord.